# declaring variables inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

```
    <script>

   var c = document.body
   var e = document.createElement("div");
   e.className = "box";

   for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {

     c.appendChild(e);
   }


 </script>
```

When I run this for loop, only one div is created in the browser. However, 
if I add a console.log(e) into the loop and run it on a console, (i.e)

```
 <script>

   var c = document.body
   var e = document.createElement("div");
   e.className = "box";

   for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
     console.log(e);
     c.appendChild(e);
   }

</script>
```

the output is

```
"<div class='box'></div>"
"<div class='box'></div>"
"<div class='box'></div>"
```

I know that I can correct the issue by declaring the variables inside the for loop, but I'm not sure why the first code above would not work?

Comment: Ok, I've made edits to make my question more clear.

Comment: You’re literally calling `createElement` exactly once… even if you log that element multiple times…

Answer (score 2):

I suppose [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) entry from MDN covers that:

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference
>   to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its
>   current position to the new position** (there is no requirement to
>   remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other
>   node).
>
> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document
>   simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first
>   removed, then appended at the new position

Answer (score 0):

It's what you expect of a variable.

`e` is a reference to the created div, not the actual `constructor`. So `appendChild` can only add the `element` once to the DOM, otherwise it would replace it to the new position, since an element is unique within the DOM. Of course `console.log` will list the same reference trice.

The solution is, as you said, to create a different element within the loop:

```
   for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
     const e = document.createElement("div");
     c.appendChild(e);
   }
   document.window.appendChild(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var div = "<div class='box'></div>";
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    document.queryselector("body").innerHTML += div
  }
</script>
```